# The remote server returned an unexpected response 417 when using SSIS to connect to SharePoint

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to connect to a SharePoint list (SP 2010, on-premise) using SSIS 2012.  I downloaded the SharePoint Adapter for SQL Server 2012 and am following the MSDN tutorial on "Extracting and Loading SharePoint Data in SQL Server Integration Services".

For the life of me, I can not seem to get the connection set up.  I've added a SP Connection using Connection Manager, and a corresponding Data Flow task of the type "SharePoint List Source".  When I test my connection, I get a 417 error message (below).  I have spent all day looking for a solution online - various false starts, but still no luck.

Others have suggested that I suppress the `expect100continue= true` property by setting it to false, but since I am using SSIS I am not sure where to make this configuration change - please help!

```
Error at Data Flow Task [SharePoint List Source [2]]: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (417) Expectation Failed. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (417) Expectation Failed.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Exception rethrown at [0]:

```
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ListsService.ListsSoap.GetListAndView(GetListAndViewRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ListsService.ListsSoapClient.ListsService_ListsSoap_GetListAndView(GetListAndViewRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ListsService.ListsSoapClient.GetListAndView(String listName, String viewName)
   at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.Adapter.ListsAdapter.GetSharePointFields(String listName, String viewId)
   at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ListServiceUtility.GetFields(Uri sharepointUri, NetworkCredential credentials, String listName, String viewName)
   at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListSource.GetAccessibleSharePointColumns(String sharepointUrl, String listName, String viewName)
   at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListSource.ValidateSharePointColumns()
   at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListSource.Validate()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostValidate(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)
```

Comment: Looks like your URL is wrong. You only want the root.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the SharePoint adapter from CodePlex in SSIS under the SQL Server 2008R2 environment.  It was tricky to set up and perhaps I can be of some assistance, even though I have not used the 2012 version.  There are a few issues I recall that may be related and can help.

- Since the SharePoint server was running on a different server than the SQL database, I had to apply the built-in SharePoint web service in order to access the XML-formatted information.  I was pulling information like the document name, who updated, last updated and so forth and importing that into the database.
- Make certain you are providing the correct information in the SharePoint data source in SSIS.  Under Component Properties there are three required fields that must be populated in order to establish the connection: Site URL, Site List Name, and View.  I recall having difficulty determining the correct Site List Name to enter because of the way SharePoint was set up.  It was very customized.  The steps defined in the following link for SharePoint will help verify whether you are applying the correct Site List Name (Site ID).

  http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-find-out-site-id.html#.VV4qZunbKUk
- The other thing to look out for once you are connected is to modify the mapping in the SharePoint adapter.  By default it will map all of the SharePoint fields available in the XML.  This can cause a memory problem, which I reported to CodePlex a few years ago.  In case it has not been resolved, just remove the mapping links that are not applied.  The following link will help with the setups.

  http://blogs.msmvps.com/ivansanders/2011/07/24/ssis-sharepoint-list-adapters/

Hope this helps.